# Is it allowded to use paypal for purchases Non-consumables services in ios app

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

We are building chat application where user needs to pay to start chat conversation to  another users that is register in the application, once the user pay he will have life time access to chat with that user. Now my concern is, Does apple allows us to use third party payment service such as paypal or stripe for this kind of model or do we need to implement the in app purchases that apple provides.

Comment: Nope. Purchases for app functionality require Apple's IAP.

Comment: @rmaddy I am unable to add paypal will you help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077157/issue-whlle-set-up-pay-pal-for-ios-sdk

Comment: @BlackTiger will you asisst me

Comment: please have a look at this tutorial: https://tigerraj.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/getting-started-with-paypal-payment-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

For purchase real-word item , I there is no restriction.

And there is "paypal ios sdk" built for you: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

---

But to purchase app-functionality, you are required to use IAP, reference: https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-and-stripe-tos-and-fees

Comment: have you gone through apple guidelines for payment ?

Comment: what I find is : if you use apple pay, there is some restriction. if you use paypal, free to go. And i am building a app using paypal.

Comment: You can only use outside payment for real world purchases. Payment for app functionality must use Apple's IAP.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, yes, I find it : https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-and-stripe-tos-and-fees . I will edit my answer, thanks for point it out

Comment: Yes the concept of enabling certain service in application need to implement IAP, but we need to have  fixed Reference Name and product ID.  
My condition is little different. User is not paying to enable chat service, instead user is paying to chat to other user.  So if user want to chat with 5 people he needs to pay five times.  

So In this case can we implement IAP. I  doubt.